# Rails prawn date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, format

I'm trying to format a date (inside of an inherited prawn class) from a db and "paste" it into a prawn generated pdf. I thought I could use my properly formatted code from one of my views but I get an error saying "unknown method l". It seems like the Prawn::Document can't access the date formatting helper method?. Is there a way to get access to it?

Here is my code from the view.

```
<%= l(course.begindate, format: "%a %d.%m.") %> - <%= l(course.enddate, format: "%a %d.%m.%Y") %>
```

Maybe it is possible to do something like this?

```
@coursedate = l(course.begindate, format: "%a %d.%m.").to_s
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Prawn::Document` doesn't incorporate view helpers, it seems. But you can use `I18n.l` for this.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok, how would I do that? Isn't there a way to let Prawn incorporate view helpers?

Comment: Change the code in your Prawn::Document to `I18n.l(course.begindate, format: "%a %d.%m.").to_s` and it will work. You can of course also put `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` (or any other helper) at the top of your Prawn::Document to include specific helpers.